# what does this </> mean? or does it even mean anything?

Tags: html, syntax

Just curious does this: `</>`, do anything? I saw this twice and I don't know if they were both typos or if they actually do something?

Answer (score 1):

If you saw it in a HTML document, it's probably a typo. HTML does not allow for anonymous element closing tags (even if the name can be inferred from context).

Outside of HTML, I understand that some SGML parsers *might* support this syntax, but I don't believe any latter-day web browsers support it.

Maybe it's a closing `</p>` element and the typist didn't apply enough pressure to the <kbd>p</kbd> key?

Comment: Hold on it was an href actually. it was "/" actually. in the form of <a href="/"></a>. What does that mean?

Comment: @JoshGret What part don't you understand?